# Integration of $\arctan$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

This question seems so silly, yet I want to know if this is true!

I know for a fact that the following is true$$\int \frac{1}{1+x^2} \,\text{d}x = \arctan(x) + C$$

But does this mean this is true also? $$\int \arctan(x) \,\text{d}x = \frac{1}{1+x^2} + C$$

My guess is that it ISN'T true but I don't know how to explain it.

Comment: No, why *would* it?

Comment: Well, it isn't true, and instead of trying to explain why it isn't, I would just say there is no reason it would.

If $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$, why would $f$ be the antiderivative of $F$ ??? Well, in almost every cases, it isn't

Comment: Do you know what an anti-derivative is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. All it means is the following
$$\int \dfrac{dx}{1+x^2} = \arctan(x) + C \iff \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\arctan(x)\right) = \dfrac1{1+x^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have been explained already why it is not true.

If you need more proof, using integration by parts, you could find that $$\int \tan^{-1}(x)\,dx=x \tan ^{-1}(x)-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(1+x^2\right)$$

Comment: This, a priori, still doesn't show why the resulting expression is not that of OP's :~p.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD. Yes, I know and I told it in my fist sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You must know it.$$\displaystyle \int f'(x){\rm d}x=f(x)+C$$